# Need an unobtrusive method for logging

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

So, I'm supposed to design a method that I would use to log everything my app does and I was thinking of doing something like this in my methods:

Declaration:

```
public static void Write(string text, params object[] parameters) {}
```

Usage:

```
if (Log.On) Log.Write("Hello", valueA, valueB, valueC);
```

So this is elegant and clean in my view. However it has one big flaw, the values are not labeled in any way. For me, the obvious solution is a method like this:

```
public static void Write(string text, Dictionary<string, object> parameters) {}
```

but this method will clutter my code.

```
if (Log.On)
{
Dictionary<string, object> p = new Dictionary<string, object>();
p.Add("valueA", valueA);
p.Add("valueB", valueB);
p.Add("valueC", valueC);
Log.Write("Hello", p);
}
```

Any ideas how to make this method as unobtrusive as possible?

Comment: Look at log4net or similar logging frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public static void LogValues(string text, object values)
{
    var properties = values.GetType().GetProperties();
    Log.WriteLine(text + ": " + string.Join(", ",
        properties.Select(property =>
        {
            var name = property.Name;
            var value = property.GetValue(values);
            return name + " = " + (value != null ? value.ToString() : "null");
        })));
}
```

Like this:

```
int x = 5;
double y = 7.2;
LogValues("Some message", new { y, s = "test", x });
```

Which will generate a line like this in your log:

```
Some message: y = 7.2, s = test, x = 5
```

The key here is in using the anonymous type for the `values` parameter. This lets you pass in "named" variables, instead of just the values of those variables.

If you want a consistent ordering on the `<name> = <value>` pairs printed out, you can insert a `.OrderBy(property => property.Name)` before the `.Select(...)` in the LINQ query.

Comment: Loving this, but I'm also concerned about the speed, any streamlining possible?

Comment: I'm not concerned about speed. In my case, database queries are real bottlenecks and compared to them some reflection during logging is negligible .